Significato di “dare/avere i bottoni alla schiena”
In Uno, nessuno e centomila di Pirandello si legge:

E intanto, non so, quasi automaticamente pensavo che a Stefano Firbo, da piccolo, avevano dato i bottoni alla schiena e che sebbene la gobba non gli si vedesse, tutta la cassa del corpo era però da gobbo: eh sì, su quelle esili e lunghe zampe da uccello: ma elegante; sì sì: un falso gobbo elegante; ben riuscito.
E, così pensando, mi parve chiaro tutt’a un tratto ch’egli dovesse valersi della sua non comune intelligenza per vendicarsi contro tutti coloro che, da piccoli, non avevano avuto come lui i bottoni alla schiena.

(grassetti miei).
Non trovo una spiegazione di cosa siano questi “bottoni alla schiena” e, s'è per questo, non trovo neppure moltre altre occorrenze dell'espressione. L'unica che ho trovato è un altro passo pirandelliano: in “Cose che capitano ad uno scrittor di commedie” riporta una lettera che immagina gli scriva Martino Lori, suo personaggio di Tutto per bene, in cui si legge:

Ma sa che lei è davvero irritante? Non so, vorrei raffigurarmelo come uno di quei falsi gobbi ammogliati e vestiti con una special cura troppo evidente, che da piccoli ebbero i bottoni alla schiena; la gobba non pare; ma tutta la cassa del corpo è da gobbo. Mi fa questa impressione, quando leggo i suoi libri o assisto alle sue commedie

dove torna anche l'immagine del “falso gobbo”.
Qualcuno, fonti alla mano, sa trovare una spiegazione di questa espressione?

Non ho mai sentito questa espressione e non ho idea di cosa significhi. L'unica idea per fare una ricerca è che potrebbe essere una espressione usata in Sicilia, di derivazione francese, o anche francese antico, come ce ne sono tante e come ce ne sono tante anche a Napoli. Perché bottone viene dal francese bouton , che a sua volta viene dal francese antico bouter, che vuol dire anche colpire, frapper. https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bouter/10752 o anche https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bottone/

Oppure potrebbe anche significare prendere a cinghiate, per punizione, con cinghie per punizione che avessero qualcosa come dei bottoni, delle borchie. Insomma, il contesto mi fa pensare a una aggressione fisica, anche per la connessione con l'idea di deformità del corpo, e per la rabbia che suscita: "vendicarsi contro tutti coloro che, da piccoli, non avevano avuto come lui i bottoni sulla schiena".

Non ho trovato fonti ma il senso sembra essere quello di un correttore, tipo un corsetto che veniva abbottonato da dietro, sulla schiena, per cercare di correggere difetti fisici come in questo caso una schiena tendente alla gobba.

Alle congetture di chi ha commentato, che comunque ringrazio molto, ne aggiungo una mia. Tra i numerosi significati riportati da GDLI alla voce “bottone”, il n. 12 si riferisce a vari strumenti medici, tra cui il cauterio: cf. https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol-ii/2, p. 335 (immagine 340). Chissà se Pirandello si riferiva a qualche pratica terapeutica che lasciava effetti negativi.

Ripensandoci, la spiegazione più plausibile mi sembra quella di Mr. Black, ho letto su internet qualcosa sui ragazzini, attuali, che devono usare il corsetto per una scoliosi, e sono sofferenze, è plausibile che sia qualcosa che porta alla rabbia descritta nel testo. Perché 'avere i bottoni alla schiena' deve essere qualcosa di fisicamente pesante, che dà rezioni forti, continuativo, e anche qualcosa di usuale per i bambini del tempo.  E chi sa quali altre pratiche mediche fossero usuali. Certo, anche le percosse non è che fossero rare, proprio l'altra sera vedevo un film su David Copperfield.

E si credeva, ed è anche vero, si sa ora scientificamente, che i bambini  picchiati possono avere problemi di sviluppo fisico. Quell'espression 'dare', 'avere' i bottoni è strana, ma chi sa. Direi che per rispondere, a questo punto non si tratta tanto di fare una ricerca linguistica, occorrenze non se ne trovano, ma storica sulle usanze dell'epoca, mica facile.

Per quanto ho visto su Google libri, sembra che ci sia una spiegazione su questo libro: La letteratura italiana: storia e testi. Volume 64: tomo V. Narratori dell'Ottocento e del primo Novecento. Riccardo Ricciardi editore.

È vero, @Charo, bravissima! Lo vuoi mettere come risposta? O preferisci che lo faccia io?

@DaG: Non posso metterlo come risposta perché non riesco a leggere la spiegazione. Fallo tu, per favore.

L'edizione di Uno, nessuno e centomila all'interno del tomo V di Narratori dell'Ottocento e del primo Novecento, a sua volta volume 64 della serie “La letteratura italiana: storia e testi” edita dalla Ricciardi commenta le parole su cui verte la domanda con una nota a piè di pagina:


avevano ... schiena: l’avevano preso in giro, schernito.


(a p. 494 del tomo). Quindi, a quanto pare, il senso è che quel personaggio, per qualche deformità fisica, che pure non era una vera e propria gobba, aveva subito delle derisioni da bambino e questo doveva aver condizionato il suo carattere da adulto.
 Ringrazio Charo per la segnalazione di questa nota.

L'espressione è strana, ho provato a cercare 'tirare i bottoni', pensando a qualcosa lanciata per scherno, e in effetti mi è uscita una spiegazione, su una pagina Facebook: "Invece "tirare i bottoni", con il significato di 'lanciare frecciate, ferire a parole', ha tutt'altra origine. Nei secoli passati, i "bottoni di fuoco" erano particolari strumenti che, una volta arroventati, servivano a cauterizzare le ferite. Di qui l'immagine di bottoni (intesi come punte) di fuoco".  https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=5467414076637858&id=228770323835619&set=a.229130470466271

Ecco una spiegazione/conferma sulla Treccani (voce "Attaccare un bottone") https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/articoli/parole/Modi_di_dire2.html

Interessante, grazie @BakerStreet !
